# how to pass value of input textbox and its id to javascript function so it makes post request via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i got some editable textbox inside html table cells! Each textbox got a summit button. I want send value of textbox and id of textbox to javascript function so it makes ajax post request to php script and edit mysql row!

My problem is that i dont know how to pass textbox value and its corresponding id to javascript and change textbox button on response of ajax.Does my buttons need unique ids as well ? could any one show me how this can done.Thanks

```
 $table3.="<tr>";
 $table3.="<td>" . $row['ID'] ."(".$totalRows. ")</td>";
 $table3.="<td bgcolor=\"#FF0000\"><input type=\"text\" id =\"". $row['ID'] ."\" name=\"". $row['ID'] ."\" value=\"edit\"><button onclick='setNewValue(\"".$row['ID']."\")'>Edit this Row</button></td>";
 $table3.="<td>" . $row['imgPURL'] . "</td>";
 $table3.="<td>" . $row['imgUrl'] . "</td>";
 $table3.="<td>".$line."</td>";  echo "</tr>";
```

javascript :

```
<script>
function setNewValue(a,b) {
var button = $(event.target);  // get button here

var text = $("#"+a);
var textboxvalue = text.val();

//alert("inputId:"+a+"\nuInputValue:"+b);


    var url = "./edit.php";
    $.post(url, {
        "method": "post",
        "rowId": a,
        "rowValue": textboxvalue,

    }, function(data) 
       {

          var ajaxResponse = data;

        //alert("success"+ajaxResponse);

            if(ajaxResponse.indexOf("SuccessEdit")>=0)
            {
              //remote the edit button
               button.hide();
            } 
            else
            {
              //change caption of edit button to try again
             button.text("some text");
            }

      })
    }

</javascript>
```

Comment: [possibly duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160456/get-the-textbox-text-using-ajax-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1):

pass the id of the input box through the function like  setNewValue(23)

function setNewValue(id){

$("#"+id);

}

Thats it you can get all the values of the input box and

this works if name the submit button with an id or rather a class;

Comment: thanks for replies. Ivin Polo Sony could you tell me how i can pass the id of inputbox to the function ? I tried this but it gives me erros!<button onclick=\'setNewValue(\" . $row['ID' . \")\'>edit this row</button>. After passing id of inputbox how can access value of inputbox itself ?

Comment: @user1788736 you can simply pass the is through the function parameter    like this <input type = "button" onclick=" setNewValue(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)" /> thats it.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$table3.= "<td bgcolor=\"#FF0000\"><input type=\"text\" id =\"". $row['ID'] ."\" name=\"". $row['ID'] ."\" value=\"edit\"><button onclick=\'setNewValue()\'>Edit this Row</button></td>";
```

to:

```
$table3.= "<td bgcolor=\"#FF0000\"><input type=\"text\" id =\"". $row['ID'] ."\" name=\"". $row['ID'] ."\" value=\"edit\"><button onclick=\'setNewValue(" . $row['ID'] . ")\'>Edit this Row</button></td>";
```

Then in your js:

```
function setNewValue(id){
    var text = $("#"+id);
    var value = text.val();

}
```

**update, hide button or change caption**

```
function setNewValue(id){
    var button = $(event.target);  // get button here

     // change caption 
     button.text("some text");

     // hide 
     button.hide();

}
```

Comment: srain the value of textbox is dynamic and editable. in your example you just put it edit! how to pass whatever user put in the textbox to javascript. I removed ,\"edit\" part and i get lots of error!

Comment: thanks i was keep trying var textboxvalue = $('input[id=+a]').val(); and it was not working . but now i get both id and textbox value in javascript. Now how i can remove the button or change caption of button if depending on ajax response from ajax call? i want somehow user know that edit was successfull. or forexample how to change bgcolor of inputbox on ajax response ?

Comment: @user1788736, how is the issue going?

Comment: srain there are more then one button in the page i just want to change the one that was clicked if the result of ajax resposnse is SuccessEdit(if(ajaxResponse.indexOf("SuccessEdit")>=0))! do i need to provide each button with unique id as well?

Comment: in function `setNewValue()`, `var button = $(event.target); ` get the button you clicked.

Comment: i put var button = $(event.target);  button.hide(); after if(ajaxResponse.indexOf("SuccessEdit")>=0) and the button never disappeared !

Comment: Put `var button = $(event.target);` at the first line in function `setNewValue()` body.

Comment: Would you paste you latest code in the question, let me have a look.

Comment: thanks srain for helping me. I edited my first post you can see it above.

Comment: Does the ajax post callback function work? Will something alert if un-comment `//alert("success"+ajaxResponse);` ?

Comment: add `button.text("xxxx");` after `var button = $(event.target);`, does this work?

Comment: I saw you create another question, have you tested the code mentioned in above two comments, I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Thanks i got the button working in the other thread but only need to know how to change background of that table cell that holds the input textbox!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $table3.="<tr>";
 $table3.="<td>" . $row['ID'] ."(".$totalRows. ")</td>";
 $table3.="<td bgcolor=\"#FF0000\"><input type=\"text\" id =\"". $row['ID'] ."\" name=\"". $row['ID'] ."\" value=\"edit\"><button onclick=\'setNewValue(this)\'>Edit this Row</button></td>";
 $table3.="<td>" . $row['imgPURL'] . "</td>";
 $table3.="<td>" . $row['imgUrl'] . "</td>";
 $table3.="<td>".$line."</td>";  echo "</tr>";
```

the 'this' will reffer to the button element that gets clicked.

```
function setNewValue(btn) {
   var cell = btn.parentNode.querySelector("input[type='text']");
   var input = cell.querySelector("input[type='text']");
   var inputId = input.id;
```

...

Answer (score 0):

you can pass this like a normal js parameter ==>

```
<input type=text id = <?php echo $row['id'];  ?> onclick= setNewValue(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>);


    function setNewValue(id){

    var obj = $("#"+id);

    console.log(obj);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind if he is using the  element the default type is submit and his entire form will probably submit. add either type="button" or use event.preventDefault() on the JS event.